# Thymleaf to fetch map value from key without foreach?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a pojo class with some fields and hashmap and i want to get this values in thymleaf without using foreach just by key name.

following is my thymleaf code ,

```
<th:block th:if="${rights.getUserRights().get("isAdmin") == true }">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon mdi mdi-undefined"></i><span>show</span></a></li>
</th:block>
```

in above code i want to display this block if user has admin rights.

below is my pojo class fields code ,

```
private long id;
private Map<String,Boolean> rights;
```

In above code i am storing details of user id and its rights but how do i fetch this value in if condition?

Comment: What's the problem?  Your code looks correct (except you might need to use a single quote `'` instead of a double quote `"` and `isAdmin`).

Answer (score 0):

After some reading i found solution which is silly i needed to add single quotes instead of double quotes as metroids said in above comment. and after that i got null context error which got solved by adding ? expression to chech if null

```
${rights.getUserRights().get("isAdmin")} ?${rights.getUserRights().get("isAdmin") == true }
```